# Its possible to Publish SCORM course direct in to web (HTML)?

Tags: html, scorm

I don't understand nothing about SCORM - but my e-learning system was broken.. (TI needs 2 weeks to solve the problem) - and I need to show the content of 1 course for some new employees.

I have the SCORM file - its possible to publish this file directy into web ONLY TO WATCH the presentation (of course, without any e-learning tool) - or I need to convert the file?

I work fine with FLASH - and SWF files.

tks a lot!!
Daniel

Comment: If you have a HTML file in the package try running it on a web sever. Locally, flash global security will stop a browser from running flash, but you can change that setting if you google it.   It mostly depends if the content is programmed to run without a LMS API. Most I've seen are.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that will be dependent on how the content is authored and whether it can fall back to playing when it doesn't find the SCORM API objects in the browser's object list. SCORM content generally requires a player which provides the API that the content uses to communicate with the LMS. In many cases the content is likely to error out when it can't detect the requisite API objects that it is supposed to be using, but it doesn't have to.

Additionally it could be multi-SCO content which would require the SCORM content player to provide the facility to move from one SCO to the next, and potentially to launch the first SCO. In this case the user might experience the first SCO (or none) and then not be able to move forward through the rest.

Finally if there is any sort of interaction or assessment (quiz) in the content, for instance to determine pass/fail or a score, then the results of which would not be captured.

(Shameless plug: for your use case you might consider signing up for a SCORM Cloud account for the limited amount of delivery you need. It allows you to import a course, send invitations, and track results for very small sets (or big ones too) of e-learning. https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/)